# jQuery show hide sliding panel from left side

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a panel to slide from left edge of browser when clicking a button and hide the panel when clicking the same button (toggle).

Html

```
  <div class="panel">
  </div>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slider-arrow show">&raquo;</a>
```

CSS

```
.panel {
width:300px;
float:left;
height:550px;
background:#d9dada;
position:relative;
left:-300px;

}
.slider-arrow {
padding:5px;
width:10px;
float:left;
background:#d9dada;
font:400 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
position:relative;
left:-300px;
}
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
$('.slider-arrow.show').click(function(){
    $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
      left: "+=300"
      }, 700, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
      $(this).html('&laquo;').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
});

$('.slider-arrow.hide').click(function(){
    $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
      left: "-=300"
      }, 700, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
      $(this).html('&raquo;').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
});
});
```

It is showing the panel but not hiding the panel.  Any problem with the selectors used?

http://jsfiddle.net/Paramasivan/eHded/1/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As others have said with jQuery once the document is initialized its only looking for elements that initially existed.  For that reason your `.show` function was being run every time.

Instead of looking for a click event on `.slider-arrow.show` you can just look at `.slider-arrow` and then check for the classes once it has been clicked like in this example.

```
$(function(){
  $('.slider-arrow').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('show')){
    $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
      left: "+=300"
      }, 700, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
      $(this).html('&laquo;').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    }
    else {      
    $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
      left: "-=300"
      }, 700, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
      $(this).html('&raquo;').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');    
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/4/

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using jQuery to manipulate the "show" and "hide" *after* the DOM has loaded, jQuery doesn't know those elements exist.

`Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call...`

I suggest using jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in order to delegate events and select dynamically generated classes, like so:

```
$(document).on('click','.slider-arrow.show',function(){
  ....
});

$(document).on('click','.slider-arrow.hide',function(){
  ....
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/2/

Answer (score 3):

I think you can manage the action choosing from the active anchor class like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.slider-arrow').click(function(){
  var anchor = this;
  var removeClass = "show";
  var addClass = "hide";
  var diff = "+=300";
  var arrows = "&laquo;";
  if($(anchor).hasClass("hide")){
    diff = "-=300";
    removeClass = "hide";
    addClass="show";
    arrows = '&raquo;';
  }
  $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
    left: diff
    }, 700, function() {
    // Animation complete.
      $(anchor).html(arrows).removeClass(removeClass).addClass(addClass);
    });     
  });   
});
```

So you've got only one animation function.

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/5/

Comment: Arrows are not changing

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `.slideToggle()`, put inside a `.click(function(){/*in here*/})`.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `$('.slider-arrow.hide').click(func.....`, that binds the `click` event at the time that code is first ran (probably when the document is ready). If you change the DOM later on (ie. add the `.hide` class) you need to re-bind the `click` event.

You need to use jQuery's `.on()` method instead (http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(document).on('click', '.slider-arrow.show', function() { /*.......*/ });

$(document).on('click', '.slider-arrow.hide', function() { /*.......*/ });
```

A better alternative altogether however would be to use CSS3 transitions and jQuery's `.toggleClass()`

```
.panel {
    left: -300px;
    transition: left 1s;
    /* other styles... */
}

.panel.expand {
    left: 0;
}

$('.slider-arrow').click(function() {
    $('.panel').toggleClass('expand');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this task I use [**SlideReveal**](https://nnattawat.github.io/slideReveal/) jQuery plugin.

After you include the library the setup is as easy as:

```
<div id='slider'>Hello World!!</div>
<button id='trigger'>Trigger</button>

<script>
  $('#slider').slideReveal({
    trigger: $("#trigger")
  });
</script>
```

Please refer to documentation for more details and live samples.