# how to make a simple Jquery sliding menu?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm very new to JQuery.
I want to build a very simple sliding menu which slides in from the left of the browser.
I have two divs and I want the menu to slide in when I click on the #div2 and gets back in when I click on it again. here is my JQuery code:

```
    $("div2").click(function(){
    $a = 0;
    if ($a == 0){
        $(this).css({"left":"100px"});
        $("#div1").css({"left":"0px"});
        a = 1;
    }else
    {
        $(this).css({"left":"0px"});
        $("#div1").css({"left":"-100px"});
        a = 0;
    }
});
```

and this is my html codes:

```
 <div id="div1" style="background-color:#0066CC; position:fixed; width: 100px; height: 500px;left:-100px; top: 50%; margin-top: -250px " ></div>
 <div id="div2" style="background-color:#093; position:fixed; width: 25px; height: 100px;left:0px; top: 50%; margin-top: -50px " ></div>
```

I tried everything I've found but no result.
thanks in advance.

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392453/jquery-show-hide-sliding-panel-from-left-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Issues is in ur code

**first** :

```
$("div2").click(function(){
```

you should call ur div by `id` or `class`.. so ur code should be

```
$("#div2").click(function(){
```

**second** :

For maintain flag value `$a`... it should be declare as `global` so declare ur variable `$a` before `click`.. like

```
$a = 0;
$("#div2").click(function(){
```

**Third**

You have declared the flag variable as `$a` but inside the code u have used `a`... so it should be

```
$a = 1; 
$a = 0;
```

*finally ur jQuery code*

```
$a = 0;
$("#div2").click(function(){  
    if ($a == 0){
        $(this).css({"left":"100px"});
        $("#div1").css({"left":"0px"});
        $a = 1;
    }else
    {
        $(this).css({"left":"0px"});
        $("#div1").css({"left":"-100px"});
        $a = 0;
    }
});
```

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/IwaPeqUQ/1/edit)

Comment: thank you very much. but what are these "console.log($a)" and "console.log("sdfDS")"?

Comment: Since you're new to jQuery, I would advice you not to abuse the $ sign for variable naming. $ sign should be used to distinguish jQuery objects from other variable. ex. `var $div2 = $('#div2'), a = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">      </script>


<script>
function show() {
    $("#div2").animate({ width: "100px" }, 500);
}
function hide() {
    $("#div2").animate({ width: "0px" }, 500);

}

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

<div id="div1" style="background-color:#98bf21;height:100px;width:10px;position:absolute;" onclick="show();"></div>
 <div id="div2" style="background-color:red;height:100px;width:0px;position:absolute" onclick="hide()"></div>

</body>
</html>
```